# Split Array into Vertical like array

Tags: javascript, arrays

my current result has this:

```
  [ '1', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '2', '4', '0', '0' ],
  [ '3', '7', '0', '0' ],
  [ '4', '0', '0', '-1' ],
```

Now i want these array to be split into vertical like the below ones:

```
    [
        1,
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        4,
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        7,
        0,
        0
    ],
```

thanks for advance to those who will help.

Comment: What have you come up with? show us your effort

Comment: Im still searching or the right for this.

Comment: what is the logic of dropping the last entry? how would you display this as required? in a web page? in a browser console? is this node?

Comment: Yes i'm kinda working on a nodes

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz - I'd also like to know how the "current result has this" ... that's not a structure that is in any way valid in javascript

Comment: @Tramyer What do you want to achieve? expalion bit more

Comment: wow - confusion!! name change in the midst of responding to questions :p

Comment: @JaromandaX You tagged me :D

Comment: Is it that bad to change my name? Cause im new to this stackoverflow

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz - OP's name change confused me :D (I'm cold, and there's wolves after me - Grandpa Simpson)

Comment: @Tramyer - no, it isn't - just confused my old brain :p

Comment: im trying to convert the javascript extracted nodes into json nodes. And im new to javascript

Comment: @Tramyer I am asking for explanation what do you want to do... from your data it seems that you want to remove first column and last row in case of a matrix. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah something like that

Comment: im creating a function that my array the top one could have a result of the below one when i run my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice` to remove content.

Here are docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```js
var matrix = [
  [ '1', '1', '0', '0' ],
  [ '2', '4', '0', '0' ],
  [ '3', '7', '0', '0' ],
  [ '4', '0', '0', '-1' ]
];

matrix = matrix.slice(0, matrix.length -1);
matrix = matrix.map(arr => arr.slice(1));

console.log(matrix)
```

Comment: funny but it didn't sliced my result i wrote it like this as a function.

Comment: @Tramyer Where is your input argument ?